# C# BackgroundWorker ReportProgress Int32?

Tags: c#

I want to display progress from a `BackgroundWorker` to a `ProgressBar` in the UI. What I dont understand is why the `BackgroundWorker`'s `ReportProgress` function takes an `Int32` when the `ProgressBar` can take a `double` value for progress. My process is very intricate and I need to make decimal progress updates. It doesnt help if I have to keep adjusting everything to the nearest integer. Can anyone suggest someway i can work around this?

Comment: It is an Int32 but it's also limited to a 0..100 (%) range. But this is aimed at the 'resolution' of the User, it should be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ProgressChangedEventArgs Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.progresschangedeventargs.aspx) can take an optional `UserState` value. You can pass anything you want to this (including for example a double value). Set it with the [ReportProgress method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

ReportProgress also has a second variant where it takes an object as an additional parameter:

```
public void ReportProgress(
    int percentProgress,
    Object userState
)
```

Simply pass your `double` as the userState object.

On a side note: Are you sure your Progress bar has so many pixels that you need a `double` to enumerate them all?